# ModX(Revolution) How to make complex FAQ with Template Variables

Tags: templates, modx

I have a single page with with 3 different groups of FAQ's.
I need to present all of these in a single page, I thought about doing it in the template variable.
So here is an example I have found over the web for the kind of complexity that I need.
Is that doable with modx?
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be better off using one of these dedicated FAQ extras:
http://modx.com/extras/browse/?search=faq

Or try the MIGx TV if you can figure out how to set it up :)
http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/MIGX

Comment: Thanks, do you think it is doable with WayFinder? I mean i can create each question as a document, and display the list and content using wayfinder, no?

Comment: You could but it's really inefficient and will be a pain to manage. A typical database entry for a document contains up to 40 fields, and you will only be using 3 or 4 of them. That's a lot of overhead. It's much better to use something built for the task, such as FAQmanager. It's not hard to set up :)

Answer (score 0):

It sure is, you can get this kind of functionality by using normal page resources & the getResources extra.  Template variables will slow things down, use the introtext & description  fields for your questions & answers. If you need to group them into categories, separate them into hidden parent resources & tickle the getResources call as necessary. The docs for it are here: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/getResources